# EF doesn't track changes for enherited types

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework 6 version.
I have such relations

```
public class Maintenance {
  [Key, ForeignKey("Configuration")]
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Text {get;set;}
  public Configuration Configuration {get;set;}
}

public abstract class Configuration {
 [Key]
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public Maintenance Maintenance {get;set;}
}
```

the Configuration class is actually the basic class for many types of configurations

for ex. SimpleConfiguration : Configurations{...}
ComplexConfiguration : Configurations {...} e.t.c.
The EF mapping for enheritance looks like:

```
Map<SimpleConfiguration>(x => x.Requires("Type").HasValue(0));
Map<ComplexConfiguration>(x => x.Requires("Type").HasValue(1));
```

so when I create a new configuration and save it _db.SaveChanges() - all works fine. 
for ex.

```
var maintenance = db.Maintenance.Find(maintenanceId);
maintenance.Configuration = new SimpleConfiguration();
db.SaveChages();
```

but when I'm trying to update existing configuration

```
maintenance.Configuration = new ComplexConfiguration();
db.SaveChanges();
```

doesn't work at all. Also I've tryed

```
maintenance.Configuration = null;
maintenance.Configuration = new ComplexConfiguration();
db.SaveChanges();
```

nothing...

At least I've found solution

```
var config = db.Configurations.Find(configId);
db.Configurations.Remove(config);
db.SaveChanges();

maintenance.Configuration = new ComplexConfiguration();
db.SaveChanges();
```

so I should twice fix changes. But I'm wondering is EF doesn't check that Configuration is changed by Type. Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

In EF you can't change the type of an existing entity once it's created, as stated [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/860d7913-7baa-43e9-a2a7-83b25ad9c558/changing-the-type-of-an-entity-that-is-part-of-an-inheritance-hierarchy?forum=adodotnetentityframework). So if you need to replace one configuration by another you need to delete and create, as you are doing.

Comment: thnx for the answer, creating SP for conversions this is a good idea

Comment: Glad it was useful. Actually I don't like sp option but it's up to you. Please don't forget marking as solved! Regards

Comment: Sometimes sp might really help with performance improvements. Anyway, thnx for help :)